# Adding hover tool to DataTable widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

using Bokeh 0.12.6 / Python 3.6:
Is there a way to add a hover tool (similar to bokeh.models.HoverTool for plots) on a bokeh.widgets.DataTable widget? It doesn't look like it's an api feature yet, so I'm looking for some guidance on the best way of achieving this?

Perhaps I can tinker with the final HTML document with Bokeh embedded inline and add a HoverTool javascript object associated with the SlickGrid table?

Comment: There is no inbuilt hover tool for a bokeh data table. A relatively crude solution could be to use a HTML template formatter for the datatable within python, and use a combination of JS and CSS to create a hover effect over each cell. Alternatively, it is likely possible to achieve the desired effect with altering the final HTML document like you suggested